# Running a 1024x768 app in a 800x600 display with the use of a downscaling transform

Tags: graphics, scaling

Is  there any application which allows to run a, let's say 1024x768 application in a 800x600 display with the use of a downscaling transform? I know that with videos this can be done, but with interactive apps could this possible? It would be some sort of a wrapper or emulator (no virtual machines please, as they add unnecessary layers of complexity).

One advantage of such an app would be to check several resolutions without having the need to fiddle with general screen resolutions. Sounds a little weird but could prove as a nice programming challenge for those who are fond of it.
If you find the ideia impractical, just leave as it is, we all are here to learn, and everybody can have their moments of fun while coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your application in a `vnc` (maybe `x11vnc`), and do the scaling with the `vnc` client (`vinagre`).

The application will not be as responsive as a native application, but should be sufficient for testing purposes.

I just came across [run_scaled](https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled), which can be used to run an application scaled. It depends on a fairly recent version of `xpra` that is available for ubuntu [here](http://winswitch.org/downloads/).

Comment: I have run this command-line "run_scaled --scale 0.5 --sleep 5 glpeces" but without success. Glpeces is a trangram game which was built only for 1024x768 resolutions. If only I could shrink it a little bit, it would be ok.  But nonetheless, I appreciate your efforts. I haven't tried vnc and vinagre because I don't know if I can run both on the same machine and if this does not poses security issues.

Comment: Hey, sorry, and excuse me for my little mistake, I just forgot to put the "=" (equals) sign after the scale parameter. It is working fine now. Good job, you saved my day!  :-)